# how to convert qt5-designer generate .ui file to .py file?

Tags: gui, user-interface, python-gui

I tried to convert the `.ui` file which is generated using qt5 designer to `.py` but all those ways are different some are working some are not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in different ways but finally, get to know the solution for that.

Open the terminal and type the below command in it.

It will generate `.py` file:

```
 pyuic5 -x main.ui -o main.py # pyQt5 version
```